# can we remove floating zero before decimal point in BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
BigDecimal bd1= new BigDecimal(0.000);
bd1 = bd1.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println("bd1 value::"+ bd1);
```

I get the following `0.00` for bd1, but I want bd1 as `.00` not as `0.00`. Am I applying the methods correctly?

Comment: You can do this with `java.text.DecimalFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `BigDecimal` to a `String`, and then use a regex to conditionally remove the leading zero, if it exists:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(0.000);
bd1 = bd1.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();
String bdString = bd1.toString().replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")
System.out.println("bd1 value::"+ bdString);
```